# Making floating social icons vertical

Tags: html, css

I'm working on this site: http://www.bedriftsdesign.no and got two things I'm struggling with:

First the floating social icons on the left in the header won't allign vertically. I'm using display:block and a bit unsure what I'm doing wrong?

Secondly (optional) I'd prefer them to be on the background element just outside the wrapper, but unsure how to make that work?

Any suggestion on how to solve this would be really welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ans of Question 1** just remove `float:left;`from here `#social li` its working as per your requirement :-  see the attached image

[image]

**CSS**

```
#social li {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

**Ans of Question 2**

I think you are looking this :-

[image]

**CSS**

```
#social {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    left: 177px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 12;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. removing float didn't do it alone, but by combining two answers and using your answer for question 2 and setting left to 5px did it. Thanks for all the anwers here. All good.

Answer (score 1):

You are floating the list elements `li` and trying to undo it by setting `display: block` for the containing anchors `a`.

You shouldn't set `li` to be `float: left;` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Find this rule

```
#social li { float: left; list-style-type: none; display:block; }
```

and remove `float:left;` This will align the icons vertically.

In order to align them along the header image, I would use negative `margin`. Find this rule:

```
#social{ background: transparent; margin: 0; }
```

and change the margin to `margin: -35px;`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by align them vertically. To what do you want them to align?

If you want them from up to down change:

`#social li { float: none; }`